# how to write unit test for a factory method in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, factory

I have a factory method that looks like this:

```
createApp: function(appType, subjectType, appIndicator) {
          if (appType === 'newApp') {
            return Restangular.all('v1/app').post({appType: appType, appIndicator: appIndicator}).then(function(app) {
              $state.go('app.initiate.new', {appId: app.id});
            });
          } else {
            return Restangular.all('v1/app').post({appType: appType, subjectType: subjectType, appIndicator: appIndicator}).then(function(app) {
              $state.go('app.initiate.old', {appId: app.id});
            });
          }
        }
```

and i want to write unit tests for it...but i'm not really sure where i can start to test it. I've only really wrote unit tests for factory methods that are a lot simpler than this (like simple math functions)

i'm using karma + jasmine for testing and so far i wrote something like this which is failing.

```
it('should return a new application', function(done) {
      application.createApp().then(function(app) {
        expect(app.appType).toEqual("newApp");
        done();
      });
    });
```

any tips on how to go about testing osmething like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
What you have done is wrong. You will have to mock the factory call.

spyOn(application,'createApp').and.callFake(function() {
    return {
      then : function(success) {
             success({id: "abc"});
         }
    }
});

it('should return a new application', function(done) {
      spyOn($state, 'go');
      application.createApp();
      expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```